# Understanding promise behavior in fetch response

Tags: xml, http, promise, fetch

This is a modification of the original post. I was able to distill my problem down, and while I have a workaround would like to understand what's different (i.e. I don't completely get why it's doing what it's doing...and want to)

Context: This is JS running in the browser, making a call to a proxy server to get around CORS issues. The proxy server is grabbing XML from an RSS feed.

The browser JS code exhibits the following behavior:

```
fetch(example.com/rss)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str,"text/xml"))
    .then(data => { 
          const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
          //data is empty here so error
    });
```

when I eliminate the middle `then` and do the parseFromString in the other handler, I get desired results:

```
fetch(example.com/rss)
    .then(response => (response.text())
    .then(data => { 
            var data = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data,"text/xml");
            const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
            //works!!!
}
```

Can anyone explain the difference in behavior? Is there a difference between `Window.DOMParser` and `new DOMParser`?

Comment: In the client-side JS case, what you’re ending up looks to be just the textContent of the response, right? I mean, it’s not HTML but instead just text — the concatenation of all the text nodes in the document.

Comment: Aagghhh...I see the error but I'm not sure why it's causing the behavior. My `apt.get` has an argument `req` and then at the bottom of the function I redefine it in `var req = https.request(options, callback).end();` Possibly a timing hole is causing req to get interpreted differently?

Comment: The client code shown in the question still elides the code you’re using to process the XMLDocument that your `window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml")` call returns. To troubleshoot further, you probably want to inspect the response in the Network pane of browser devtools and “preview” the response body there and see what that shows in the XML response you expect, or instead if it‘s already the same text-nodes-concatenation shown in the snippet in the question.

Comment: Thanks that tip was useful. I saw that `data` appeared empty, so I was able to hack a workaround. I'd really like to understand the issue though (and fix it in a non-hacky way), so will be modifying the question.